# ExtJS Ext.form.Panel with JSONP

Tags: extjs, jsonp

Is it possible to use JSONP with `Ext.form.Panel`?

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom binding. Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'container',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'user',
            proxy: {
                callbackKey: 'callback',
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://localhost/data2.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'user'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                load: function() {
                    this.onload();
                },
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },
    onload: function() {
        // do something with this.store.data
    },
    listeners: {
        destroy: function() {
            delete this.store;
        }
    }
});
```